# Loops, tables structures

Tags: java, loops

I'm a beginner in Java and I am going crazy over this problem. So pretty much I just started learning loop nesting and am trying out several problems in the book which I'm struggling with.

The question in the book asks me to,

> Write pseudocode for a program that prints a Celsius/Fahrenheit
>   conversion table such as the following.

```
 Celsius | Fahrenheit 
 --------+-----------
       0 |         32
      10 |         50
      20 |         68
      ...         ...
     100 |        212
```

The code that I have written is,

```
public class table
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;                       
        System.out.println("Celsius | Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("--------+-----------");
        for ( i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {            
            for (int c = 1; c <= 1; c++)
            {                
                System.out.print("    " + i + "  |");
                double sum = (i * (9.0/5.0)) + 32;  // formula for celsius to fahrenheit conversion
                System.out.printf("%d5", (int) sum);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My code doesn't seem to convert the Celsius to the number of Fahrenheit. It just prints big numbers, also
How can I change my code to get an organized table. Please help! I wanted it to be like the one that example asks me to do.

Comment: What the 2nd for loop is doing.?

Comment: If your book asks you to write pseudocode, then why are you trying to write Java?

Comment: Second loop only executes once - just remove it.

Comment: What do you need nested loops for in this example?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra loop.  And in the format you probably mean `"%5d"`.  `"%d5"` is adding a `5` to the otherwise correct numbers!

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Celsius | Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("--------+-----------");
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d   |",i);
            double sum = (i * (9.0/5.0)) + 32;  // formula for celsius to fahrenheit conversion
            System.out.printf("%5d", (int)sum );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

With these modifications it produces:

```
    Celsius | Fahrenheit
    --------+-----------
        0   |   32
       10   |   50
       20   |   68
       30   |   86
       40   |  104
       50   |  122
       60   |  140
       70   |  158
       80   |  176
       90   |  194
      100   |  212
```

Which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is not printing big number, it is just that you have provided `"%d5"` as the printf pattern, causing a "5" appended to the number you printed.  Therefore, instead of showing "32" on screen, it shows "325" now

I don't really understand why you do so but I guess you want `"%5d"` instead

To make your code even more readable, put the output in one line instead of splitting them into segments with so different way, e.g.:

```
    for ( int c = 0; c <= 100; c += 10)
    {
        int f = (int) (c * (9.0/5.0)) + 32);  // C to F
        System.out.printf("%5d | %5d\n", c, f);
    }
```

Comment: C to F isn't a good comment. A much better way would be a static method with full Name. The 'i' is wrong, isn't it`

Comment: @userunknown ya, that `i` is wrong as I missed that when I am copying from OP's code.  C to F isn't very good, I have it there just to let people be able to link it back to the original line in OP's code, for which the comment is exceptionally long  :P  Quality of comment and refactoring to method etc is not the main topic of discussion here anyway

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the inner for loop which is unnecessary rest of the code is correct..

```
public class table
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Celsius | Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("--------+-----------");

        for ( i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {    
            System.out.print("    " + i + "  |");
            double sum = (i * (9.0/5.0)) + 32;  // formula for celsius to fahrenheit conversion

            System.out.printf("%5d", (int)sum );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should have renamed table to Table and moved declaration of i into the for-head.

Comment: I did not try to change the whole solution, I am just trying to make the code he wrote work. This can be solved by writing fewer lines but I am not trying to do that I am just trying to make it work what he wrote.

Comment: Why do you abandon his formatting attempts? What do you mean with C syntax? You'd better introduce a method for computing the celsius2farenheit.

Comment: I change this System.out.printf("%d5", (int) sum);
yes, you are right ideally he should have done it in a function.

Comment: Did you have a look at your output? Just changing the original "%d5" to "%5d" and Roys output looks much better than yours, without producing a clean, number length agnostic table.

Comment: yes you are right in pointing out that I just updated the code